# Collection<T> RemoveAt vs RemoveItem

Tags: c#, generics

Collection.RemoveAt(Int32) Method vs Collection.RemoveItem(Int32)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1.removeat?view=net-6.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1.removeitem?view=net-6.0

What is the difference between these two methods?  According to the docs RemoveItem is virtual and RemoveAt is not, and that is the only difference I can find.

The excerpted source code looks something like this

```
    IList<T> items;

    ....

    public void RemoveAt(int index) {
        if( items.IsReadOnly) {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException(ExceptionResource.NotSupported_ReadOnlyCollection);
        }

        if (index < 0 || index >= items.Count) {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        RemoveItem(index);
    }

    ...

    protected virtual void RemoveItem(int index) {
        items.RemoveAt(index);
    }
```

https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/objectmodel/collection.cs

So my question more properly is why are there two very similar methods differing only by being virtual or not?  What is the use case?  Is this just historical cruft?  What's the story?

Comment: Well the one removes an entry at a certain index, the other removes an entry no matter where the entry is found in the list

Comment: @RandRandom "_the other removes an entry no matter where the entry is found in the list_"; that would be `Remove`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay - ah, sorry, my bad, thats what I get from reading to fast

Comment: `RemoveItem` is meant to be overridden in a derived class implementing some custom behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Reason for having two methods is to allow consumer to create subclass of `Collection<T>` that will override behavior of inserting\removing items. You can override `InsertItem`, `RemoveItem`, `SetItem`, `ClearItems`.

For example, you can override this methods in subclass to send events (like ObservableCollection) or to log any collection change.

Comment: So what additional value does RemoveAt bring?  I mean could just use RemoveItem on ObservableCollection and since it is overridden I'll get the Observable behavior.

Comment: I wonder if RemoveAt came first but since it wasn't virtual RemoveItem had to be added as virtual to allow derived classes to modify the behavior without breaking existing inheritors?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `RemoveAt` includes this interesting note at the bottom of the page:

> Derived classes can override RemoveItem(Int32) to change the behavior of this method.

The ultimate conclusion is that `RemoveAt` calls `RemoveItem`, and that derived classes override the behavior by overriding `RemoveItem`.